# iterate through dict and only use 3 row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a a csv file I importer into a dict. 
Is there a way to iterate through the dictionary and only only grab the links and pass them into a list to iterate into bs4?

```
with open('/Users/paribaker/Google Drive/Paxwin/Data/cits.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for k, v in row.items():
            print(k, v)
```

the result is:

```
id 166
city NO Norway
link http://www.fallingrain.com/world/NO/
id 167
city NP Nepal
link http://www.fallingrain.com/world/NP/
id 168
city NR Nauru
link http://www.fallingrain.com/world/NR/
id 169
city NS Suriname
link http://www.fallingrain.com/world/NS/
id 170
city NU Nicaragua
link http://www.fallingrain.com/world/NU/
```

Comment: seems that dictreader doesn't help here: your data is different on each line. seeing a sample of your input file would help.

Comment: `[row['link'] for row in reader]`

Answer (score 3):

Based on your output:

```
with open("/Users/paribaker/Google Drive/Paxwin/Data/cits.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    links = [row["link"] for row in reader]
    print(links)  # or do whatever you want with the list...
```

**edit**:
If the input CSV is huge (like millions of rows), you might want to find the location of your `link` column and read the rows as lists instead of converting each row into a `dict`. Something like:

```
with open("/Users/paribaker/Google Drive/Paxwin/Data/cits.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    index = next(reader).index("link")
    links = [row[index] for row in reader]
    print(links)  # or do whatever you want with the list...
```

Comment: Converting to a dict is not that expensive. If the CSV is huge, ou should just iterate over it and process the lines line by line like OP is doing, instead of making it into a single list like you are doing.

Comment: It's vastly more expensive than doing it yourself. On my system, with OPs CSV structure and a million rows the first one takes 4.3 seconds, while the second one takes only 0.8. And the difference would be far greater if there were more than 3 columns. Yes, you can parse by hand the lines too and probably shave off another half a second, but the `csv` module correctly handles eventualities like quotations and escapes that you would have to deal with yourself and the pay off is far lesser than just not using the `DictReader` when you don't really need it.

Comment: Sure, for massive data processing like that, you are right, convenience should probably be thrown to the wind.